# @2x retina images not working on iOS7

Tags: html, ios, css, image, retina-display

I have added some images to a website via the html img srcset tag and using the css background property.

The images do not show up on iOS7 devices for some reason and I cannot understand why. I have tried using both iOS8, iOS7.0 and iOS7.1 - iOS8 works across all devices and iOS7.0/1 does not work at all.

- Displays correct on Macbook retina

This is 'alright' when using the img srcset tag because it will default to the 1x image, however for a css background tag it will show nothing.

I have had a hunt around and none of the other 'solutions' I have found worked.

```
body { 
    background: black url('../background/image.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    background-size: 1379px 1000px;
}

@media
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-resolution: 192dpi){
    body { 
        background-image: url('../background/image@2x.jpg')!important;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`srcset` is not supported in iOS 7 http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset

Comment: ok, thanks, any ideas why the media query wouldn't be working though?

Comment: no reason why it should not work, by only looking at the css code you've posted. You wouldn't even need the evil `!important` - can you create a fiddle that replicates the issue?

Comment: Ok, this is really strange - I have now tried loading in a different file using the same method and it works.... so it must be something to do with the file itself... -.-

Comment: Check out my blog post about the optimal solution to delver retina images to all possible devices: http://blog.benmarten.me/best-way-to-optimize-website-images-for-all-possible-retina-sizes/